# turning a callable / bound method into something more readable to humans?

Tags: python, function

I've got some code where I build a no-parameter function to return a value from some distribution.  I've got a set of these partial functions built with different parameters for different test cases, as such:

```
dist1 = functools.partial(random.expovariate, 1.0/64.0 )
dist2 = functools.partial(random.uniform, 128, 128)      
dist3 = functools.partial(random.uniform, 100, 156)       
dist4 = functools.partial(random.randrange, 4096)
```

And a sample call using two of this distributions as parameters might be:

```
runSim(env, rate=dist1, size=dist2, source=dist3)
```

Eventually, I need to have output where a row of results is the output from the simulation as well as the parameters that were passed into that particular test run. If I try to directly print() the callable I've created, I get something like this:

```
>>> dist1 = functools.partial(random.uniform, 100, 156)
>>> print(dist1)
functools.partial(<bound method Random.uniform of <random.Random object at 0x2059788>>, 100, 156)
```

What I ultimately WANT to be able to is "reverse extract"(!!?!?) what this bound method is made up of, so I can print something that makes more sense to the end consumer, such as:

```
print(f"Distribution type is {x}, param1 is {y} param2 is {z}")
```

where here, x would be "expovariate" and y,z would be 100,156.  My debugger tells me that the bound method has args of 100,156 but it's not clear to me how to access those and way less clear how to get the info on what has actually been bound.

So I guess the actual question is "how do I deconstruct(?) a bound method to show it's component parts?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial function has the orginal function and arguments attached as attributes.

You can create a small helper function to print this information:

```
>>> def print_partial(partial):
...     print("Partial {} with args {} and kwargs {}".format(partial.func.__name__, partial.args, partial.keywords))
...
>>> print_partial(dist1)
Partial expovariate with args (0.015625,) and kwargs None
```

Alternatively, you can wrap functools.partial in a class with a custom `__str__()` method:

```
class Distribution:
    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
      self.partial = functools.partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Distribution or type {} with args {} and kwargs {}".format(self.partial.func.__name__, self.partial.args, self.partial.keywords)
```

Answer (score 1):

`partial` has the attribute `args` that stores the arguments you passed when you defined it, and `func` that stores the function object. Just print the function's name and the arguments:

```
print(f'Distribution type is {dist1.func.__name__}, param1 is {dist1.args[0]} param2 is {dist1.args[1]}')
```